# How to write a fallback mechanism that saves entities that weren't successfully saved the first time

Tags: java, database, persistence

I am trying to write a mechanism that will manage my save to DB operation.

I send the server a list of objects, it iterates them and saves each one.

Now, if they fail for some strange reason (exception) it saves them to another list that 
has a timer that runs every 5 seconds, and tries to re-save them.

I then have a locking problem, which I can solve with another boolean.

My function that saves my lost object is:

```
private void saveLostDeals() {
    synchronized (unsavedDeals) {
        if (unsavedDeals.size() > 0) {
            for (DealBean unsavedDeal : unsavedDeals) {
                boolean successfullySaved = reportDeal(unsavedDeal,false);
                if (successfullySaved) {
                    unsavedDeals.remove(unsavedDeal);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my `reportDeal()` method that's being called for regular reports and for lost deals report:

```
try {
    ...
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
       ...if (fallback)
     synchronized (unsavedDeals) {
            unsavedDeals.add(deal);
        }
        session.getTransaction().rollback();

    } finally {
       ....
    }
```

Now, when a lost deal is saved - if an exception occurs - the synchronized block will stop it.

What do you have to say about this save fallback mechanism?  Are there better design patterns to deal with this common issue?

Comment: If it fails the first time why would it succeeed a second time? Or are you writing it somewhere else other than the same db?

Comment: If he uses optimistic locking, commits can fail because of stale data. One strategy to deal with it is to re-try the transaction (which includes refreshing the data from the database)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using either a [`proxy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) or `aspects` to handle the rollback/retry mechanism. The proxy could use something like the [`strategy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern for advice on what action to take.

If you however don't want to retry immediately, but say in 5 seconds as you propose, I would consider building that into the contract of your database layer by providing asynchronous routines to begin with. Something like `dao.scheduleStore(o);` or `dao.asyncStore(o);`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends

For example,

Request to save Entity ---> Exception occurs ---> DB Connection Problem----> In Exception Block Retry to save entity in fallback DB-----> Return the response to request

Request to save Entity ---> Exception occurs ---> DB Connection Problem----> In Exception Block Retry to save entity in in-memory Store of Application -----> Return the response to request

Request to save Entity ----> Exception occurs----> unknown Exception----> In Exception block save entity to XML File store[serialize in XML]---->Return the response mentioning temp saved will be updated later to request

Timer ----> checks the file store for any serialized XML ----> updates the DB

Points to watch out for

1. Async calls are better in such scenarios rather than making requesting client to wait.
2. In case of in-memory saving , watch out for amount of data saved in memory in case of prolonged DB failure. That might bring down the whole application
3. Transactions, whether you want to rollback of save its intermittent state.
4. consistency of data to be watched for

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have a question regarding your first point. Why are async calls better? With async calls I will need to manage the request Id myself. Currently I am using a proxy service and this way I plan on working pseudo sync (with time outs).